# Missing phonegap-1.3.0.js for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Where can I find phonegap-1.3.0.js file iOS. In package it is there for Android.

Presently I'm using phonegap-1.2.0.js, which I found somewhere. Now I need 1.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution.

just create a new phonegap project in xCode and don't include the "www" folder.

Just run the project. Now goto the foledr in which project is located.

You can find the folder "www" in which the phonegap.js is located